# Ruby on Rails 3 to 4 "Unkown Validator KeyValidator"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the Learn Rails 3 by Example video tutorials by Michael Hartl, pretty early stage but I've run into a small issue and I'm wondering if it has to do with my using rails 4 while the tutorials use rails 3.

In the demo_app I have a model called "micropost" which looks like this:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, :key => { :maximum => 140 }
end
```

In order to keep the maximum length of an entry to 140. This is exactly what the video tutorial shows to enter, unless I'm being blind.

But now when I try to open localhost:3000/microposts, it throws back this error:

```
ArgumentError in MicropostsController#index
Unknown validator: 'KeyValidator'
```

Same with the rails console, if I try to type user.microposts is gives me the same error.

Is this something that was changed in rails 4? What do I do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to set a maximum length, you should use [`length`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length):

```
validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 }
```

Comment: Alright, so it looks like it's changed since his tutorial. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

yehh Dex is right:

**for better understanding please go [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates)**

```
validates :first_name, :length => { :maximum => 30 }
```